# JavaScript fetch: Error JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

Tengo un problemilla que me está comiendo la cabeza.

Tengo un fetch, debajo lo dejo, en el que en mi máquina local no tengo ningún problema en recoger el response y el data. En cambio, cuando lo subo al servidor, me da el siguiente error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```
export const DETAIL_URL = 'admin/retrieve-image.php';
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${DETAIL_URL}?id=${this.state.idImage}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
            loaded: true,
            imageData: data[0]
        })
    });
}
```

El JSON que la URL me devuelve es el siguiente:

```
[{"id":"3","author":"Zander","title":"Rocket Raccoon","path":"images\/1553253832.jpg","guest":"0","source":""}]
```

Es un JSON válido, así que no se por qué me está arrojando ese error al hacer el fetch.

Añado:

También he probado de incluir en el fetch un segundo parámetro con el id como data:

```
fetch(DETAIL_URL, {
    method: "GET",
    data: {
        "id": this.state.idImage
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

Al visualizar lo que devuelve:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>Raccoon Junkyard</title><link href="/static/css/main.a05f6569.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script>!function(l){function e(e){for(var r,t,n=e[0],o=e[1],u=e[2],f=0,i=[];f<n.length;f++)t=n[f],p[t]&&i.push(p[t][0]),p[t]=0;for(r in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,r)&&(l[r]=o[r]);for(s&&s(e);i.length;)i.shift()();return c.push.apply(c,u||[]),a()}function a(){for(var e,r=0;r<c.length;r++){for(var t=c[r],n=!0,o=1;o<t.length;o++){var u=t[o];0!==p[u]&&(n=!1)}n&&(c.splice(r--,1),e=f(f.s=t[0]))}return e}var t={},p={1:0},c=[];function f(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var r=t[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return l[e].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,f),r.l=!0,r.exports}f.m=l,f.c=t,f.d=function(e,r,t){f.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},f.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},f.t=function(r,e){if(1&e&&(r=f(r)),8&e)return r;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof r&&r&&r.__esModule)return r;var t=Object.create(null);if(f.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:r}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof r)for(var n in r)f.d(t,n,function(e){return r[e]}.bind(null,n));return t},f.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return f.d(r,"a",r),r},f.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},f.p="/";var r=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],n=r.push.bind(r);r.push=e,r=r.slice();for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)e(r[o]);var s=n;a()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/2.49d07c2a.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.2cf2361b.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

PHP de la página que debe devolver el JSON:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = ".$_GET["id"];
$result = dbQuery($query);

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: por que no logeas la cadena de texto y verifica lo que trae, podrias hacerlo asi: `.then(res => res.text()).then(text => console.log(text))`

Comment: Yo diría que lo mas probable es que cuando subes al servidor, la petición que haces no te está devolviendo un JSON. Puedes verificar también desde el inspector del navegador que uses en la pestaña de `Network`, ahí puedes ver las peticiones que se hacen y verificar qué respuesta te dio el servidor

Comment: Con cuerdo con @German, Adicional Cheshire si te fijas se esta quejando por el token `< ` el cual no pertenese a un json, seguro que la respuesta es un json? y no un html con json.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa he actualizado lo que devuelve, parece ser que está devolviendo una página. Me resulta extraño ya que tengo otros fetch que no me dan este problema

Comment: @GermanAlzate exactamente, me está devolviendo una página html en lugar de un json. En cambio, si entro en la página directamente en el navegador, me devuelve un JSON

Comment: Listo, ya vi la actualizancion. Cuando dices: `Me resulta extraño ya que tengo otros fetch que no me dan este problema` esos otros fetch apuntan a otra direccion?, Como te comento @German verifica en el Network y revisa que [Códigos de estado HTTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP).

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Los otros fetch apuntan a la misma carpeta admin/otro-archivo.php. En ambos archivos, solo hay un `echo json_encode($result)`, nada más se printa, ni espacios en blanco en la primera ni última línea ni entre medio.

Comment: Podemos asegurar que las direcciones a las que llama el fetch son las correctas? no vaya a ser que en produccion haya un proxy o algo, y este llamando a la direccion equivocada

Comment: @gbianchi son las correctas. Si antes de hacer el fetch saco por consola la url completa, la página me devuelve un JSON: http://raccoonjunkyard.com/admin/retrieve-image.php?id=3
pero al hacer el fetch, me devuelve HTML.

Comment: esa direccion efectivamente devuelve un json. Cuando haces un get a esa misma direccion, deberia devolver el mismo json. Estas haciendo un get a otro lado, definitivamente

Comment: @gbianchi parece ser que si, ahora que me doy cuenta, al dejar el ratón encima de la URL que hace el fetch en la pestaña Network, está buscando en otra dirección que termina con /admin/retrieve-image.php (algo como pagina.com/detalle/admin... en lugar de pagina.com/admin...)

Comment: con f12 podes ver la consola del navegador, y ahi podes ver a donde es exactamente la llamada que hiciste al apretar el boton. Tenes la url completa que llamo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien decía @gbianchi, la URL no era la correcta.

Al estar en una ruta `mi-pagina.com/detalle`, la constante `DETAIL_URL = 'admin/retrieve-image.php';` apuntaba a la dirección `mi-pagina.com/detalle/admin/retrieve-image.php` en lugar de `mi-pagina.com/admin/retrieve-image.php`

La solución fue añadir una ruta absoluta a la URL del fetch.

`DETAIL_URL = '/admin/retrieve-image.php';`

Comment: Si lo has arreglado de este modo, recuerda marca tu misma respuesta como solución válida. Así, los siguientes que vengan buscando solución o pretendan ayudar verán que ya está solucionado. Un saludo.

Comment: @Emerita lo se, para marcar como respuesta correcta una propia, hay que esperar 2 días

Comment: Ya, jejejejeje, mas que nada, lo digo para que no se te pase. Que así mantenemos un orden, dentro del caos que tenemos. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema de conversión a formato JSON. Asegura que response contiene un JSON.

Puedes comprobar los valores de esta manera:

```
.then(response => response.text())
.then(data => {
    var check1 = data;
    var check2 = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(check1);
    console.log(check2);
    this.setState({
        loaded: true,
        imageData: data[0]
    })
});
```

Si la comprobación es correcta cambia **response.json()** por `response.text()` y usa conversión manual con JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 0):

Pruebe con esto señor

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = ".$_GET["id"];
$result = dbQuery($query);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: No hay suerte con ello, gracias por comentar.