# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal, controller, sesiones

os cuento, estoy realizando un login y a la hora de que el jquery reciba la respuesta del Ajax me da el siguiente error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Este es mi codigo AJAX & Jquery

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#btn-inicio-sesion" ).on( "click", function() {
        var form_data={
                        debug:              "true",
                        valor_user:        $("#usuario_logIn").val(),
                        valor_pass:        $("#password_logIn").val()
                    };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?r=sesiones/BuscarUsuario",
            data: form_data,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success:function(respuesta_consulta){
                console.log("Va to bien");
                console.log(respuesta_consulta.respuesta);
                if(respuesta_consulta.respuesta == "1"){
                    console.log("Coinciden");
                }else{
                    console.log("no coinciden");
                }
            },error:function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log('message=:' + data + ', text status=:' + textStatus + ', error thrown:=' + errorThrown);
            }
        });         
    });
});
```

Este seria el controlador de sesiones

```
    require "model/sesiones.php";
    $valor = "0";
    $usuario = sesiones::findUser($_POST["valor_user"], $_POST["valor_pass"]);
    if(!empty($usuario)){
        $valor = "1";
    }else{
        $valor = "0";
    }
    error_log(json_encode(array( "response" => "good", "respuesta" => $valor,"message" => "Va todo bien")));
    echo json_encode(array( "response" => "good", "respuesta" => $valor, "message" => "Va todo bien"));
}
```

Y este seria el modal, que es solo la consulta

```
public static function findUser($usuario, $password){
    $sentencia ='SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `Usuario` = "' . $usuario . '" && `password`="' . $password . '"';
    return db::singleton()->query($sentencia)->fetch();
}
```

El error_log de el controlador me devuelve el array correctamente, tal que ai

> {"response":"good","respuesta":"0","message":"Va todo bien"}

Ayuda por favor TT.TT

Comment: Revisa este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/248920/107347)

Comment: Unexpected token casi siempre es debido a un JSON mal formado. Ojo, muchas veces el JSON está bien, pero el cliente lo recibe junto con otras cosas y eso ya estropea las cosas. Basta con que saques algo por pantalla aquí por ejemplo `require "model/sesiones.php";`  así sea un espacio en blanco y ya el JSON llega estropeado. Por tanto debes verificar que no sale nada por pantalla aparte del JSON. Yo evitaría incluso escribir en el log de errores, no tiene sentido aquí, Más bien escribe en el cliente: `console.log(respuesta_consulta);` para ver lo que está llegando realmente.

Comment: También, es bueno poner esto en el servidor antes de sacar el JSON: **`header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");`** pues si por ejemplo `$valor` tiene acentos o caracteres especiales, podría producir un JSON erróneo que resultará en un error *`Unexpected token`* u otro parecido.

Comment: en el require model/sesiones.php lo unico que devuelvo es esta linea "return db::singleton()->query($sentencia)->fetch();", he probado con el header y sigue igual. El log de lo que recibe el json lo hago, o me da el error del titulo o me devuelve el <html>